# Can't comment after setting bounty

Tags: support

I had 100 points. I need 50 to be able to comment. I gave all 100 for a bounty. Now I have 27 points so I cannot comment. Is there a way to still comment ? Why don't we have allow a user to always comment once he crosses the 50 point mark ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to gain another 23 rep to comment...

Answer (score 3):

From the [bounties page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (emphasis mine):

> - All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.
> - **If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.**
> - Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.
> - Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time.
> - To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).
> - Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).
> - You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started.

If you put up your reputation for a bounty, you are giving your rep away, and you do not get it back. You lose any privileges that go along with the reputation if losing said reputation puts you below the requirement(s) for those privileges.

That's simply how the system works, and the rules are put in place for a reason: the fact that bounties are non-refundable makes them valuable, which is what brings attention to your question in the first place.

I'd recommend reading through the rest of that bounties page to get a better idea of how they work and to ensure that anyone who happens to answer your bountied question is treated fairly when the bounty approaches expiration.